# Unwanted dots when using addplot3 gnuplot

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

I'm trying to use "addplot3 gnuplot" instead of "addplot3" to plot some data, but the resulting graph is overlayed by a grid of blue dots. How can I removed it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[domain=-1:1,view={0}{90},colorbar horizontal]
    \addplot3 gnuplot[contour filled={number=32}]{ x + y };
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tell pgfplots that you do not wish to have marks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[domain=-1:1,view={0}{90},colorbar horizontal]
    \addplot3[no marks] gnuplot[contour filled={number=32}]{ x + y };
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]